# Cycles of Specified Length in a Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph, and $A$ be its adjacency matrix. Define $n = |V|$.

Given $A$ and a natural number $m \le n$, I'm interested in the following problem:

> How many **simple** cycles of length $m$ exist in $G$?

By **simple** cycle, I mean no repeated vertices along the cycle is allowed (other than the starting and ending vertices, which coincide).

The problem is NP-hard. However, I'm not asking its complexity; I'm merely interested in whether there is a closed-form expression for computing it. (Thus, computing the expression can be NP-hard.)

Comment: This is indeed NP-hard: when $m = n$, whether the number of simple cycles of length $m$ is nonzero is the Hamiltonian path problem.

Comment: @Rahul: I know. I used the word "might" since for $m<n$, it might be easier.

Comment: Hi, I asked the [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/177722/19341) without noticing yours. Sorry for that, but I got some pretty cool answers (one containing a recursive formula to calculate the number of ways without backtracking). If you are still interested, have a look. And +1 **interesting question** ;-)

Comment: Interesting, in a [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177722/19341#comment410736_177865) it is stated, that the number of cycles *can be computed in polynomial time.* So why do you say, that it is NP-hard? For a better flow of reading it would be cool, if could reply directly to Chris there...

Comment: @draks: Maybe our questions are different?

Comment: @draks: Like you, I got the impression that our questions are the same! If you agree that they're not, please tell me to "un-accept" it. You can also delete your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they are the same. I just wonder about the different complexities given by you and Chri and so I want to hear your opinion...

Comment: For the problem I stated here, I'm also pretty sure that it is NP-complete. Take a look at page 4 on [this presentation](http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/josephcclin/paper/counting-cycles.pdf), or its [full version](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.101.4120).

Comment: I think the difference is that your cycles are **simple**, no repeated vertices, while mine are **reduced** ones, no backtracking. What do you think?

Comment: @draks: That's one possible difference. Small changes in problem definition may have drastic effects on its computational complexity.

Answer (score 1):

An answer containing a recursive formula for the number of cycles can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177865/19341).

Answer (score -1):

I think the trace of $A^m$ gives the number of cycles of length $m$ of a graph $G$.

Comment: This includes cycles with repeated vertices, however.

Comment: @Rahul Narain: And counts each of them m times.

Comment: I think this does not compute the number of **simple** cycles: As Rahul pointed out, this includes cycles with repeated vertices.

Comment: I've got some answers to this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/177722/19341). Have a look if you're interested...