# What is the maximum number of nodes I can traverse in an undirected graph visiting each node exactly once?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

So I have an un-directed un-weighted graph. It contains cycles. I would like to find the path which visits the most nodes with no repeat visits to any node. Since this is a graph traversal, you can start and end at any node you like.

**Background Research:** I have looked at Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP); this problem is different and does NOT allow you to finish where you started from and there are no weights. I have looked at several other algorithms, but have found none suitable for this problem.

**Graph Size:** There are 100 nodes in the graph; with 10 disconnected nodes.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [Returning Paths on Cubic Graphs Without Backtracking](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/177722/19341)...

Answer (score 4):

This problem is still difficult, it is known as [**Hamiltonian path**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), and NP-complete. It doesn't really make a difference if the path is closed (a circuit) or not. Just ask the HAM-PATH problem for every pair of endpoints of all edges and you could solve HAM-CIRCUIT.

Comment: Thanks! What is HAM-PATH, HAM-CIRCUIT is it just your notation or some library in Matlab?

Comment: Also there may not be any Hamiltonian path or cycle in my problem, I just want to visit the max number of nodes.

Comment: No its just a short cut for the Hamiltonian Path problem, and the Hamiltonian Circuit problem.

Comment: Yeah, but the maximum could be the number of nodes and thus you can detect a Hamiltonian Path with your algorithm. Just ask if the maximum path visits all nodes.

Comment: I think I will write an algorithm of my own which will find the path which visits most nodes. Since there are 90 nodes, there are 90 * 89 combinations of start-end nodes which is roughly 8100 Hamiltonian Path problems; and I am not even sure that a Hamiltonian Path exists. So it could be an exercise in vain if I proceed with finding a Hamiltonian Path problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

> In graph theory and theoretical computer science, the longest path
>   problem is the problem of finding a simple path of maximum length in a
>   given graph. A path is called simple if it does not have any repeated
>   vertices; the length of a path may either be measured by its number of
>   edges, or (in weighted graphs) by the sum of the weights of its edges.
>   In contrast to the shortest path problem, which can be solved in
>   polynomial time in graphs without negative-weight cycles, the longest
>   path problem is NP-hard, meaning that it cannot be solved in
>   polynomial time for arbitrary graphs unless P = NP. Stronger hardness
>   results are also known showing that it is difficult to approximate.
>   However, it has a linear time solution for directed acyclic graphs,
>   which has important applications in finding the critical path in
>   scheduling problems.