# When is ${(1-t^2)^{-N/2}}{\det(f_t(A))}$ expressible as polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, matrix-equations

Given a matrix valued function $f_t:\mathbb R^{N\times N} \mapsto \mathbb R^{N\times N}$. For $f_t(A)=B$ both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. Which properties can be assigned to $f_t$, when the following division
$$
\frac{\det(f_t(A))}{(1-t^2)^{N/2}}
$$
will again result in a polynomial. Should a polynomial $f_t(\cdot)$ have some restrictions on the coefficients?

To give an explicit example (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583883/how-to-get-from-chebyshev-to-ihara)): Is $\displaystyle \frac{\det((1+2t^2)I - At)}{(1-t^2)^{N/2}}$ expressible as polynomial?

Comment: I find the question confusing: what is the relationship between $t$ and the numerator of your fraction? Maybe you meant that $f \in \mathcal M _N (\Bbb R) [[t]]$, i.e. is a formal series in $t$ with matrix coefficients?

Comment: @AlexM. $t$ is a parameter of $f()$. I edited the question...