# Which cubic graphs have an eigenvalue of $\sqrt{6}$?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Which cubic graphs have an eigenvalue of $\sqrt{6}$?

Can these graphs be constructed?

The question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1532507/19341) one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick look at GraphData[] in Mathematica, here are some simple graphs with eigenvalues of $\sqrt{6}$. That value is also in their spectrum.

[image: some graphs with eigenvalue sqrt(6)]

Ah, you're asking for cubic graphs.  Same process:

[image: cubic graphs with eigenvalue sqrt(6)]